# How to download Image from http URL that redirects to https?

Tags: android, picasso

I have spent days to try and get this to work but still no luck.
My problem is that the url redirects to a `https` version for some reason

So lets say this is the image url:

http://api.androidhive.info/images/sample.jpg

for some reason the image redirects to https like to:

`https://api.androidhive.info/images/sample.jpg`

Since my site does not have **https** it gives:

> "This site can’t be reached"

**and then no image is downloaded**

I've followed this tutorial [link](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/07/android-loading-image-from-url-http/)

I am using Picasso to load the image all the https url from youtube work from but when i call a url that has no https then it does not work

This is what version of android I am using

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.example"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
```

I have no idea what to do any help will be great.

Comment: Did you try using `Volley` library to load your images? Please refer to this link: [http://www.truiton.com/2015/03/android-volley-imageloader-networkimageview-example/](android-volley-imageloader)

Answer (score 2):

Following is just a work around or hack you can do,

> In the callback of Picasso do this:

```
//this is the url which is having https
String url = "https://api.androidhive.info/images/sample.jpg";

//in callback of picasso which is overriden when some error occurs do this steps

String newUrl = url.replace("https", "http");
Picasso.with(context)
.load(newUrl)
.into(imageView);
```

This is just a way around

> If this way around is not working follow this link

[what JakeWharton solution for this](https://github.com/square/picasso/issues/463)

Comment: I've tried this still does not work even if the url is http://api.androidhive.info/images/sample.jpg it still redirects to https for some reason?

Comment: are you using OkHttp in your application?

Comment: @knight I have added a link in my answer kindly go through it, I thinks this might solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

CustomPicasso.java

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;

import com.jakewharton.picasso.OkHttp3Downloader;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

/**
 * Created by Hrishikesh Kadam on 19/12/2017
 */

public class CustomPicasso {

    private static String LOG_TAG = CustomPicasso.class.getSimpleName();
    private static boolean hasCustomPicassoSingletonInstanceSet;

    public static Picasso with(Context context) {

        if (hasCustomPicassoSingletonInstanceSet)
            return Picasso.with(context);

        try {
            Picasso.setSingletonInstance(null);
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            Log.w(LOG_TAG, "-> Default singleton instance already present" +
                    " so CustomPicasso singleton cannot be set. Use CustomPicasso.getNewInstance() now.");
            return Picasso.with(context);
        }

        Picasso picasso = new Picasso.Builder(context).
                downloader(new OkHttp3Downloader(context))
                .build();

        Picasso.setSingletonInstance(picasso);
        Log.w(LOG_TAG, "-> CustomPicasso singleton set to Picasso singleton." +
                " In case if you need Picasso singleton in future then use Picasso.Builder()");
        hasCustomPicassoSingletonInstanceSet = true;

        return picasso;
    }

    public static Picasso getNewInstance(Context context) {

        Log.w(LOG_TAG, "-> Do not forget to call customPicasso.shutdown()" +
                " to avoid memory leak");

        return new Picasso.Builder(context).
                downloader(new OkHttp3Downloader(context))
                .build();
    }
}
```

build.gradle (Module:app)

```
android {

    ...

}

dependencies {

    ...

    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.jakewharton.picasso:picasso2-okhttp3-downloader:1.1.0'
}
```

Usage -

```
CustomPicasso.with(context)
    .load("http://api.androidhive.info/images/sample.jpg")
    .into(imageView);
```

For latest revisions check CustomPicasso gist - https://gist.github.com/hrishikesh-kadam/09cef31c736de088313f1a102f5ed3a3